# How do I reinstall ubuntu after formatting partition on windows dual boot

Tags: grubrescue

I had ubuntu 18.04 together with windows 10. I wanted to reinstall ubuntu but wasn't able to boot from usb. So I formatted the drive containing ubuntu without realizing how it would affect boot record. Now I am staring at GNU GRUB screen. Is there a way to recover from this? I if I can somehow reinstall ubuntu without having to reinstall windows as well? I have looked up but every post explains how to recover from grub rescue screen. Are these two the same thing? I'm very new to ubuntu.

Comment: Since you formatted the space with Ubuntu then you will have to reinstall it and choose that space to install Ubuntu and grub should be again installed to the efi partition!

Comment: @George Udosen I was able to boot from windows and then reinstall ubuntu on same partition. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can change the boot order so that you can use windows.Type the following in your terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line GRUB_DEFAULT=0 and change to GRUB_DEFAULT=saved.

Then execute command to update grub using

```
sudo update-grub
```

to change the boot order, execute the folowing

```
sudo grub-set-default n (n is the windows listed in grub, count from 0,1 and so on)
```

as boot items are count from 0 to n, not 1 to n.
If uh want to change again the grub boot loader you need to execute the

```
grub-set-default
```

Hope this helps you.
Thank you.!

Comment: Will OP not reinstall Ubuntu after this?

Comment: @cloud.0009 I was able to reinstall ubuntu on same partition after booting from windows. Thank you for help